# view tab in safari not allowing actual size choice

Tags: macos

I have a mac: OSX 10.9   the "actual size" choice is greyed out under View on Safari. Zoom in and zoom out and zoom text only 
 are available. How can I enable the "actual size" choice?

Answer (score 1):

It’s only available if you’ve used the **Zoom In** or **Zoom Out** menu item.

Comment: Just to add to this. If "Actual Size…" is greyed out, it means that you are already viewing the page at "actual size". If you had zoomed in or out of the page you would no longer be viewing the page at "actual size", so the menu item would then be made available to help you "reset" the page to "actual size".

Comment: thank you. a simple solution. info I did not know